# Solr Fuzzy Queries on Short words with length less than four

Tags: solr, fuzzy-search, fuzzy-comparison

I am trying a fuzzy search on the name field with the following Query.

When I run a query like `q=(name:'smiht'~0.25) AND (name:'will'~0.25)`  the records returned have names like `Will Smith`, `William D Hamilton DC`, `William I Smith JR`.

Now when I add a word like 'dc' at the end of the query like below it does not return any results.  I am expecting to see all the records with names 'William D Hamilton DC'. Does solr fuzzy queries NOT work on shorter words?  Can someone please help?

`q=(name:'smiht'~0.25) AND (name:'will'~0.25) AND (name:'dc'~0.25)`

The field type for the field name is as below.

```
 <!-- USING Exact Text with Minimum filters-->  
    <fieldType name="text_exact" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
      <analyzer type="index">
          <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Comment: I did not know how to do fuzzy search on shorter words.  I had to add logic to do an exact match if the string length is less than 4. Thanks.